# How to weight the beginnings of strings in Levenshtein distance algorithm

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to use the Levenshtein distance algorithm (in Python, if it makes any difference) to do a fuzzy string comparison between two lists of company names. An example would be where list A contains `XYZ INDUSTRIAL SUPPLY` but list B might say `XYZ INDUSTRIAL SUPPLY, INC.` but they should still match.

Right now, my implementation is terribly inaccurate. As a second example, currently the algorithm finds `abc metal finishing` and `xyz's mach & metal finishing` very similar because of their endings, but they are totally different companies. I want to improve this accuracy and one way I think I can do that is by weighting the beginning of strings somehow. If the company names are supposed to match, chances are they start out similarly. Looking at my first example, the whole beginning matches, it's only at the very end where variations occur. Is there a way to accomplish this? I haven't been able to work it out.

Thanks!

**Edit for more examples:**

Should match:

- `s west tool supply`, `southwest tool supply`
- `abc indust inc`, `abc industries`
- `icg usa`, `icg usa llc`

Shouldn't match (but do currently):

- `ohio state university`, `iowa state university`
- `m e gill corporation`, `s  g corporation`

**UPDATE:**

Progress has been made :) In case anyone is ever interested in this sort of thing, I ended up experimenting with the costs of inserts deletes and substitutions. My idea was to weight the beginning of the strings more heavily, so I based the weights off of the current location within the matrix. The issue that this created though, was that everything was matching to a couple of very short names because of how my weights were being distributed. I fixed this by including the lengths in my calculation. My insertion weight, for example, ended up being `(1 if index<=2/3*len(target) else .1*(len(source)-index))` where `source` is always the longer of the two strings. I'm planning to continue tweaking this and experimenting with other values, but it has already shown a great improvement. This is by no means anywhere close to an exact science but if it's working, that's what counts!

Comment: Instead of applying Levenshtein to the whole string, apply it to pairs of similarly positioned words in both string. That way you could assign higher weights to the matching of words near the beginning.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a little bit? I don't really understand. How would I do that? Do you mean like split each string `s`(ource) and `t`(arget) into words and loop the levenshtein alg over them? How would that work if `s` and `t` contain different numbers of words though?

Comment: Not sure. I was thinking about something similar to the way Levenshtein handles strings of different lengths, where strings of equal length have a shorter distance than those that don't. Kind of like Levenshtein distance at the word, instead of character, level. The basic idea is to give similar words near the beginning more weight than those that come later in the phrase.

Comment: I'm trying to sort this out (kinda how I said in my comment above) but I'm getting stuck figuring out how to deal with different numbers of words in `s` and `t`, as well as what I would want the weights to be if they turn out the same. Maybe even negative weights? But I'm not sure that makes any sense...

Comment: If the number of words are different, you would need to compare all order-preserving combinations of the one with larger number. The number of those combinations would be considerably less than that of all possible ones would be. Given phrase of equal length would make it relatively easy to compare pairs of words from each. Needing to leave a word out to match would have to increase the distance by some factor.

Comment: So many comparisons are going to add up though... The run time on my lists is already like 45 minutes due to the list lengths and that's really just the basic levenshtein algorithm right now.